# Sorting algorithms and Array.sort

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm studying sort algorithms and have written a function is testing every algorithm I have in a loop.
It generates an array and sorts it with algorithm which I want to test and Array.sort comparing them after that. The `problem` is that `radixSort` `mergeSort` and `quickSort` algorithms are incorrect("as my algorithm outputs ") but then I console.log `testArray` and `correctlySortedArray` `testArray` is correct but not `correctlySortedArray`. I know that `Array.sort` is `inconsistent` but nevertheless this inconsistence repeats only with these 3 sort algorithms. Here is the code:

```
import insertionSort from "./insertionsort.js"; //* we don't need brackets if the module is exported by default
import mergeSort from "./mergesort.js";
import radixSort from "./radixsort.js";
import quickSort from "./quicksort.js";
import selectionSort from "./selectionsort.js";
import bubbleSort from "./bubblesort.js";
import javascriptSort from "./javascriptsort.js";
let sortingAlgswithoutJs = [insertionSort,bubbleSort,mergeSort,radixSort,quickSort,selectionSort,mergeSort,javascriptSort];
let wrongAlgs = [mergeSort,radixSort,quickSort];
function runAlgs(){
    let success = true
    for (let i of sortingAlgswithoutJs){
        success = true;
        for (let f = 0;f<100;f++){//* each algorithm is tested 100 times
            let array = generateArray();
            let correctlySortedArray = javascriptSort(array);
            let testArray = i(array);
            if (!testAlg(correctlySortedArray,testArray)){
                //* veryfying equality of 2 algs
                console.log("This algorithm is incorrect")
                success = false;
                console.log(testArray, "testarray");
                console.log(correctlySortedArray, "javascript array");
                break;
            }
            if (f==99){
                console.log(correctlySortedArray,"javascript array")
                console.log(testArray, "testarray");
            }
        }
        if (success){
            console.log("This algorithm was successful");
        }
        
    }
}
function generateArray(){
    let arr =[];
    for (let g=0;g<5;g++){
        arr.push(Math.round(Math.random()*1000));
    }
    return arr;
}
function testAlg(array1 , array2){
    for (let k =0;k<array1.length;k++){
        if (array1[k]!==array2[k]){
            
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true
}
runAlgs();
```

This is the code for javascriptSort:

```
function javascriptSort (arr){
    let array = arr.sort((a,b)=>{a-b});
    return array;
}
export default javascriptSort;
```

Here is what it outputs in console when algorithm is incorrect:
 `[87, 171, 194, 539, 924] "testarray"`
`[539, 171, 87, 194, 924] "javascript array"`
Now when I was ready to publish this question I have an idea :`What if these 3 algs are to fast and I have problems of async nature`

Comment: `(a,b)=>{a-b}` should be `(a,b)=>a-b` or `(a,b)=>{return a-b}`. Your version doesn't return anything from the function.

Comment: it didn't help.

Comment: I just tested it and it makes `javascriptSort()` work correctly.

Comment: There's nothing async in the code you've posted.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`arr.sort((a,b)=>{a-b});`

You are passing in a function that returns nothing, use

`arr.sort((a,b) => a-b);`

When you use the block curly brackets you need to have a return statement, `{a-b}` returns undefined.